# Trouble installing packages in Debian for mit-scheme-10.1.10, Header file not found

Tags: linux, scheme, mit-scheme

Here's the error for the mcrypt module

```
checking mcrypt.h usability... no
checking mcrypt.h presence... no
checking for mcrypt.h ... no
configure: error: Header file<mcrypt.h> not found.
```

Same error for a package called gdbm.

I'm new to Linux and am running Debian 10.2.0-amd64 with Oracle VirtualBox. I'm trying to install Scheme to use with [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). I know that a (.h) file is a header file and that's about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently don't have access to any debian machines, but given Ubuntu's similarities try:

```
apt-get install libmcrypt-dev libgdbm-dev
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. What exactly did it do? Can you link the docs?

Comment: You were simply missing the development components of the libraries you're using.  On debian based systems these are typically found in packages named: <package>-dev ... that being header files and (possbily) static link libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Debian 10 (Buster), you can install MIT Scheme from the official Debian repositories instead of compiling it on your own:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mit-scheme
```

MIT Scheme package in Debian: https://packages.debian.org/buster/mit-scheme.

If you really want to compile from source:

> Here's the list of package dependencies that must be installed when building:
>
> m4, autotools-dev, libssl-dev, libncurses5-dev, libx11-dev,
> libxt-dev, libltdl-dev
>
> And here are some optional packages that are needed for specific
> purposes like crypto and databases:
>
> libmhash-dev, **libmcrypt-dev**, **libgdbm-dev**, libpq-dev, libdb-dev

Source: Chris Hanson on the [mit-scheme-devel mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mit-scheme-devel/2010-04/msg00013.html).